# Is there a way to retrieve events (appointments) from all Outlook's shared calendars?

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, outlook-restapi, netoffice

My problem is, I can't access and so iterate Outlook's shared calendars. I've tried several ways but they all take me back to the default calendar (i.e. my account calendar).

I tried to loop in the subfolders, the GetSharedDefaultFolder() method and using different types of objects of the Interop library but I couldn't solve it.

```
Here are the methods I've tried. To run the program (in particular GetMethod3() and GetMethod5()) you have to set the string "email" with your own email.

using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace OutlookTest {
    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            OutlookSharedCalendar outlookSharedCalendar = new OutlookSharedCalendar();

        }
    }

    public class OutlookSharedCalendar{

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp;
        NameSpace oNameSpace = null;
        MAPIFolder oMAPIFolder = null;
        MAPIFolder objFolder = null;
        MAPIFolder objSubFolder = null;
        Explorer objExplorer;
        AppointmentItem objCalenderItem;
        Folders objOutlookFolders;
        AddressEntry addrEntry = null;
        Items oCalendarItems = null;
        string email = "myemail@email.com";

        public OutlookSharedCalendar() {

            AppStart();
            GetMethod1();
            AppEnd(); 

            AppStart();
            GetMethod2();
            AppEnd();

            AppStart();
            GetMethod3();
            AppEnd();

            AppStart();
            GetMethod4();
            AppEnd();

            AppStart();
            GetMethod5();
            AppEnd();
        }

        public void GetMethod1() {
            oMAPIFolder = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            oCalendarItems = (Items)oMAPIFolder.Items;
            oCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
            foreach(AppointmentItem item in oCalendarItems) {

                if(item.IsRecurring) {

                    RecurrencePattern oRP = item.GetRecurrencePattern();
                    DateTime first = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01, item.Start.Hour, item.Start.Minute, 0);
                    DateTime last = new DateTime(2019, 10, 31);
                    AppointmentItem recur = null;

                    for(DateTime cur = first; cur <= last; cur = cur.AddDays(1)) {
                            recur = oRP.GetOccurrence(cur);
                            Console.WriteLine(recur.Subject + " - " + cur.ToLongDateString() + " - " + recur.Body);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject + " -> " + item.Start.ToLongDateString());
                }
            }
        }

        public void GetMethod2() {
            int intFolderCtr;
            int intSubFolderCtr;
            int intAppointmentCtr;
            // >> Initialize The Base Objects
            objOutlookFolders = oApp.Session.Folders;
            // >> Loop Through The PST Files Added n Outlook
            for(intFolderCtr = 1; intFolderCtr <= objOutlookFolders.Count; intFolderCtr++) {
                objFolder = objOutlookFolders[intFolderCtr];
                objExplorer = objFolder.GetExplorer();
                // >> Loop Through The Folders In The PST File
                for(intSubFolderCtr = 1; intSubFolderCtr <= objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders.Count; intSubFolderCtr++) {
                    objSubFolder = objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders[intSubFolderCtr];
                    // >> Check if Folder Contains Appointment Items
                    if(objSubFolder.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) {
                        // >> Loop Through Appointment Items
                        for(intAppointmentCtr = 1; intAppointmentCtr <= objSubFolder.Items.Count; intAppointmentCtr++) {
                            // >> Get Teh Calender Item From The Calender Folder
                            objCalenderItem = objSubFolder.Items[intAppointmentCtr];
                            // >> Process Appointment Item Accordingly
                            Console.WriteLine(objCalenderItem.Subject + " - " + objCalenderItem.Start + " - " + objCalenderItem.Body + " - " + objCalenderItem.Location);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void GetMethod3() {

            DateTime dtFrom = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 01, 01);
            DateTime dtTo = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);

            Recipient teamMember = oApp.Session.CreateRecipient(email);
            MAPIFolder sharedCalendar = oApp.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(teamMember, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            if(sharedCalendar.DefaultMessageClass != "IPM.Appointment" || teamMember.DisplayType != 0) {
                return; //Calendar not shared.
            }

            string restrictCriteria = "[Start]<=\"" + dtTo.ToString("g") + "\"" + " AND [End]>=\"" + dtFrom.ToString("g") + "\"";

            Items results = sharedCalendar.Items.Restrict(restrictCriteria);

            foreach(AppointmentItem item in results) {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Subject + " - " + item.Start + " - " + item.Body + " - " + item.Location);
            }
        }

        public void GetMethod4() {

            oMAPIFolder = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

            DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);
            DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 01, 01);
            string restrictCriteria = "[Start]<=\"" + dtEnd.ToString("g") + "\"" +
                                      " AND [End]>=\"" + dtStart.ToString("g") + "\"";
            StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
            Items folderItems = null;
            Items resultItems = null;
            AppointmentItem appItem = null;
            int counter = default(int);
            object item = null;

            strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            folderItems = (Items)oMAPIFolder.Items;
            folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
            folderItems.Sort("[Start]");
            resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria);
            item = resultItems.GetFirst();
            do {
                if(item != null) {
                    if(item is AppointmentItem) {
                        counter++;
                        appItem = item as AppointmentItem;
                        Console.WriteLine(appItem.Subject + " -> " + appItem.Start.ToLongDateString());
                        strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() +
                                              "\tStart: " + appItem.Start.ToString() +
                                              "\tSubject: " + appItem.Subject +
                                              "\tLocation: " + appItem.Location);
                    }
                    item = resultItems.GetNext();
                }
            }
            while(item != null);
        }

        public void GetMethod5() {

            addrEntry = oApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
            if(addrEntry.Type == "EX") {
                Recipient recip = oApp.Session.CreateRecipient(email);
                if(recip.Resolve()) {
                    Folder folder = oApp.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Folder;
                    foreach(AppointmentItem item in folder.Items) {

                        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject + " - " + item.Start + " - " + item.Body + " - " + item.Location);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

            public void AppStart() {

            // >> Start Outlook
            oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        }
            public void AppEnd() {

            // >> Close Application
            oApp.Quit();
            // >> Release COM Object
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp);
            oApp = null;

        }

    }
}
```

I hope I can get advice on the code or if someone knows a viable alternative to Interop. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `EWS API` - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/ews-managed-api-reference-for-exchange). You'll also need an account which has access rights to those particular calendars.

Comment: Could you give an EWS example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method is used to get a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example, with minor changes:

```
public void GetMethod3() {

    DateTime dtFrom = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 01, 01);
    DateTime dtTo = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);

    Recipient teamMember = oApp.Session.CreateRecipient(email);
    teamMember.Resolve();
    if(teamMember.Resolved)
    { 
       MAPIFolder sharedCalendar = oApp.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(teamMember, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
       if(sharedCalendar.DefaultMessageClass != "IPM.Appointment" || teamMember.DisplayType != 0) {
           return; //Calendar not shared.
       }

       string restrictCriteria = "[Start]<=\"" + dtTo.ToString("g") + "\"" + " AND [End]>=\"" + dtFrom.ToString("g") + "\"";

       Items results = sharedCalendar.Items.Restrict(restrictCriteria);

       foreach(AppointmentItem item in results) {
          Console.WriteLine(item.Subject + " - " + item.Start + " - " + item.Body + " - " + item.Location);
       }
    }
}
```

As you may see the recipient should be resolved against your address book before trying to access a shared calendar. The [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book.

Comment: The recipient is resolved but the foreach iterates only the items that are in the calendar of my account even if the same account has permission to read on the shared calendar. Do I miss something?

Comment: Everything looks good. Try to debug your code carefully. Are you sure the recipient created is not you?

Comment: The recipient was created with my account. Now I can see the appointments of the shared calendar by specifying the email of the same. Question: Should the email of shared calendars always be explicit or is there a way to read them dynamically? Thank you very much.

Comment: Recipients are used everywhere in Outlook - to specify TO, CC, BCC recipients. Or just entries in the address book.